# What is the area of the square given the following circumstances?

Tags: geometry, arithmetic

The perimeter of square ***HJKL*** is 2 times the perimeter of square ***WXYZ***

The [image]

SO if perimeter of HJKL is 2 times the perimeter the WXYZ than 
$$ \text{Perimeter of } HJKL = 2\cdot2(l+w)$$
 So the L and W of $HJKL = 2l$ and $2w$? so the area is $2$ times larger than the $WXYZ$?
But it looks like it was wrong.

Comment: Area $4(2^2)$ times larger than the WXYZ.

Comment: What? how did you get 4?

Comment: The area of $HJKL$ is $4$ times larger than $WXYZ$. Let $a$ be a side of $WXYZ$. Then $P_{HJKL}=2\cdot 4a$, so the sides of $HJKL$ are each $2a$, so $A_{HJKL}=(2a)^2=4a^2$.

Comment: @Olimjon It's $4$ times larger.

Comment: I did the same. Or is it a rectangle with an angle of 90?

Answer (score 4):

$WYXZ$ has side length $a$ and perimeter $4a$.

$HJLK$ has side length $b$ and perimeter $4b = 2(4a) = 8 a$, so we know $b = 2 a$.

The area of $WYXZ$ is $a^2$, and $HJLK$ has area $b^2 = (2 a)^2 = 4 a^2$, thus four times the area of $WYXZ$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing that out looks like I was using the perimeter formula for rectangular